# Why do changing adjacent lines but modifying independently cause a git merge conflict?

Tags: git

Say I start out with one commit on master in `test.txt` with just the line `Hello world!` followed by a new line (to prevent any diffs happening on the first line when adding a second line).

Then, I branch off this commit with branch name `modification`. Here I change the file from

```
Hello world!
```

to

```
Hello world!
This is another line.
```

and then I commit to that branch.

Then I check out master and change the file from

```
Hello world!
```

to

```
Hello world! This is a new thing.
```

And then I commit that onto `master`. In summary, in both commits, I just change one line. Since I had the newline on master at the beginning, the extra commit on `master` *only* modifies line 1, while the commit on `modification` *only* modifies line 2. Hence, I don't see why this results in a merge conflict when I try to merge `modification` into master. However, I get this as the `diff3` output.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Hello world! This is a new thing.
||||||| merged common ancestors
Hello world!
=======
Hello world!
This is another line.
>>>>>>> modification
```

Why wouldn't git realize that they're changing separate lines and merge those two together? I would think it would take line 1 modification from the commit on `master` and the line 2 modification on `modification` to form:

```
Hello world! This is a new thing.
This is another line.
```

The only possibility I can think of is there's something about modifying the same hunk regardless of the line number.

Interestingly, if instead on `modifications` I add `This is another line.` to line 3 instead of line 2, keeping that empty line on the `modification` branch, the merge continuous without conflicts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the right idea: Git declares a conflict if the two "sides" touch the "same lines" of the "same file", as compared to the contents of that file in the merge base commit.  The trick lies in defining *same file* and *same line*.  The merge base commit in this case—given your particular commits, that is—is your first commit ever, which had `test.txt` with one line in it, reading `Hello world!`.  The two branch tips have `test.txt` with the other contents.

Philosophically speaking, defining *same file* is a hard problem: see [the paradox of the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).  Git, however, just declares that if file `test.txt` exists in all three commits—in the merge base, and in both branch tip commits—then this is "the same file".  So that clears that problem right up.   However, "same line" is still a little fuzzy.

The change you made from the first commit ever to the first branch tip commit left line 1 alone but modified the end of the file, adding `This is another line.`

The change you made from the first commit ever to the second branch tip—the new `master` tip before the merge—changed line 1 itself.

Git gets a little squirrelly at the edges of a changed region—changes happen, in effect, *between* lines sometimes.  Those changes touch both the above and below lines.  Ultimately it's just a quirk of the algorithm chosen to decide whether the changes conflict: Git decides to say that these changes do touch the same line(s), while a different algorithm might say they don't.

(The edge effects arise from having to have nonempty intervals, to avoid fencepost issues.  The various algorithms mostly use half-open intervals: a region starts at symbol X—lines act as symbols, here—and ends before symbol Y.  The end of the file is usually assigned an EOF symbol for this purpose.  Some algorithms like to have a symbol "above" the first line as well, as sort of an SOF, or Start Of File.)