# Git merge: Why does the merge conflict when two branches modify two adjacent lines?

Tags: git

I learn that git's merge algorithm is the three way merge. But I met a situation that didn't seem to fit the algorithm.

1. init a git repo and commit to master branch this:

```
## hello
## world
```

2. create a branch named develop.
3. submit a commit that modify line **1** to **master** branch:

```
## hello-master
## world
```

4. checkout develop and submit a commit that modify line **2** to **develop** branch:

```
## hello
## world-develop
```

5. in develop branch, run 'git merge master' and conflict arose:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
## hello
## world-develop
=======
## hello-master
## world
>>>>>>> master
```

Why does this conflict arise? Doesn't **git merge** check every line?

Thanks for any insight!

I looked up the git documentation and didn't solve the problem

Comment: Git has a proximity algorithm which works this way.  The assumption is that changes which are sufficiently apart need not be flagged as in conflict.

Comment: "Doesn't git merge check every line" Yes, but to identify what line it is, Git needs a context. That means it also looks at the adjacent lines.

Comment: try with a 3-line file where the second line does _not_ change between the 2 branches.

Comment: When merging, you must first identify where in the file the changes are happening. If you add a large number of lines to a file, the position of the next change could be at a largely different line number. Therefore, merge tries to identify the position by context. If you change the adjacent line, the context is lost - which creates the conflict.

In fact, I've experienced merges where this type of conflict was real and I had to manually fix the change.

Comment: Git usually takes 3 lines of "context". That means it will include in the generated patch/diff/commit: 3 lines *before** the changed lines *and* 3 lines *after* the changed lines (e.g. see `git show <branch>`. If you change 2 lines on different branches and there are 3 or more unchanged lines in-between them - no conflicts will occur, because the context will match 100%. If the changes are any closer (e.g. 0 lines in-between as in yours) there will be conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275340/why-do-changing-adjacent-lines-but-modifying-independently-cause-a-git-merge-con. So the question will be closed.